# Simplification of a combinatorial expression

Tags: combinatorics

Is there any simplification for $M$ given as follows:

$$M=\sum_{j=1}^{m} A_j B_j$$

Where,

$$A_j=\prod_{i=0}^{m}\binom{n-i\cdot j}{j}$$

$$B_j=\sum_{h_1=0}^{j}\sum_{h_2=0}^{j}\ldots \sum_{h_k=0}^{j}\binom{n}{h_1}\binom{n-h_1}{h_2}\binom{n-h_1-h_2}{h_3}\ldots \binom{n-h_1-h_2-\ldots -h_{k-1}}{h_k}$$

I forgot to mention the following conditions:

1. $n-m^2>m$
2. $n-k\cdot m>m$

Here is my approach:

$$A_j=\frac{n!}{j!(n-j)!}\frac{(n-j)!}{j!(n-2j)!}\ldots$$

Hence,

$$A_j=\frac{n!}{(j!)^m (n-(m+1)j)!}$$

I don't think $B_j$ can be simplified but I may be wrong!

Comment: $\binom{n}{h_1}\binom{n-h_1}{h_2}\binom{n-h_1-h_2}{h_3}\ldots \binom{n-h_1-h_2- \dots -h_{k-1}}{h_k}$ $ = \frac{n!}{h_1! \dots h_k!\cdot (n-h_1-h_2-\dots-h_k)!}$

Comment: I noticed that $B_j$ follows a multinomial distribution but sum of all combinations of $h_k$ made me crazy